# What does it mean when concordance and global significance tests consistently suggest data doesn't fit model?

Tags: r, cox-model

[image]

For example, ni this image my global significance tests are all p= 0.8. Does this just mean I have to discard the results of my cox analysis? Even after adjusting for time dependent covariates I find I am getting such p-values.
Can I still use individual Pr(>|z|)for specific covariates?
Thanks!

Comment: Ordinarily you would need to provide much more detail to get a good answer. But if you have just 4 degrees of freedom for those tests, it suggests that you don't have much data relative to the complexity of your model. Parameter estimates are going to be quite uncertain (with high p-values) as a consequence.

Comment: @mkt Thanks for the reply! Do you think censoring has a part to play? I'm doing a survival analysis and over 75% of my data is censored as we don't know when the patients actually would end up dying. I'm not too familiar with the stats so all your help is super appreciated!

Comment: @mkt does this also mean I can't use individual p values for each covariate? For example, age is a covariate but the p-value is super high. I hypothesise there is no impact of age on HR as a result, but since my model is so bad, do I discard this?

Comment: @mkt I would be really grateful as I am super stuck on my research and can't progress otherwise :/

Comment: I don't know much about survival analysis, but you might get useful help here if you edit your question to include much more detail about the data, question and analysis.

Comment: To provide useful help we'd need to see more details. The low "degrees of freedom" isn't a problem by itself in this case, as that represents the number of predictors in this type of model report for a model fit by maximum partial likelihood. But your overall p values and concordance suggest that you haven't modeled anything useful at all. I'm wondering if maybe there was some problem in the way you handled censoring or time-varying covariates, but without seeing details about the data and the call your made to the model I can't say. Please use the `{}` code tool to show code and results.

Comment: I think it is the censoring because 90+ of my population survived (and I’m looking at overall survival). But does this invalidate the p-value for each covariate?